# plot data and interpolating spline with a legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, spline

Sample data:

```
x <- seq(0, 1, by = 0.1)
y <- c(1, 2.1, 3, 2, 1, 0, -3, -2, 0, 0.5, 1)
xpred <- seq(0, 1, by = 0.01)
ypred <- spline(x, y, xout = xpred)$y
y1 <- y + runif(length(y))
ypred1 <- spline(x, y1, xout = xpred)$y
nx <- length(x)
nxpred <- length(xpred)
foo <- data.frame(x = c(x, xpred, x, xpred), y =c(y, ypred, y1, ypred1),
       type = rep(c(rep("data", times = nx), rep("spline", times = nxpred))), 
       experiment = rep(c("A", "B"), each = nx + nxpred ))
```

For each facet, I would like to plot the data using blue points for the data, and a red continuous line for the spline interpolation. Also, I would like to get a nice legend, with entries "Data" and "Spline": the legend is the same for all facets, obviously. I'm able to plot the points and the line:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = filter(foo, type =="spline"), aes(x=x, y=y)) +
geom_line(color = "tomato") +
geom_point(data = filter(foo, type =="data"), color ="blue") +
facet_wrap(~ experiment, labeller = "label_both")
```

[image]

How can I add the legend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ggplot(data = filter(foo, type =="spline"), aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = "Spline")) +
  geom_point(data = filter(foo, type =="data"), aes(color ="Data")) +
  facet_wrap(~ experiment, labeller = "label_both")+
  scale_colour_manual(name="Legend",values=c("blue","tomato"))
```

If you want a legend you need to have colours in your `aes()`.
In the aes I set the names (edit as fits you) that will appear in the legend.
In scale_colour_manual I define the colours (blue and tomato)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work for you:

```
ggplot(data=foo) + 
geom_point(data=foo[foo$type=='data',], aes(x, y), col='red') + 
geom_line(data=foo[foo$type=='spline',], aes(x, y), col='blue') + 
facet_wrap(~experiment)
```

[image]